# Cygwin64 - command not working as expected

Tags: svn, cygwin

The following command string was working fine in `Cygwin32` but no longer works under `Cygwin64`. Does anyone have a clue why? All packages are installed as expected.

```
$svn status | sort | cut -c2- | xargs cksum

: No such file or directory
```

I am running on Windows 7 x64

Comment: What is the output of `svn status | sort`? What about `svn status | sort | cut -c2-`?

Comment: The output is a listing of the files in the CWD where the command is executed.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Does the output `svn status | sort | cut -c2-`, by any chance, include a blank line, or `:`, or  some other weirdness? Judging by the error, the answer is yes. That's why I wanted you to print the output, because that's almost certainly the cause of your bug - and without this information, I can't really help.

Comment: Is the command literally `$svn`, or is the `$` supposed to be a shell prompt? If it's `$svn`, what is the value of the `$svn` variable?

Comment: I am not running the command in a script but in my SVN working copy.

Comment: The intent of the command is to get the "cksum" of the files have changed in my working copy. So when I run the cmd: $ svn status | sort | cut -c2- | xargs cksum
: No such file or directory
the $ is just my prompt - not a variable declaration.


:

Comment: Without the xargs cksum part, I get this output (list of files in the working copy). I hope I am explaining this correctly. Thank you for you help (and patience!).
       applist.txt
       applist-1.txt
       build-1.sh
       build-2.sh
       build-3.sh
       build-4.sh
       make.log

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error is usually caused by a script that has Windows-style line endings.

In Unix, and also under Cygwin, the end of a line is indicated by a single LF character. In Windows, it's indicated by a CR LF pair. The CR (carriage return) character is not recognized by the shell as an end-of-line marker; it's just another character.

So if your script has a line like:

```
some_command
```

the shell will see it as

```
some_commandCR
```

where `CR` represents the return character. It will print an error message like:

```
some_commandCR: command not found
```

which, because printing a carriage return sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line, will appear as:

```
: command not found
```

That's not *exactly* the error message you're getting, but the underlying cause is the same.

You can use the `dos2unix` command to fix the line endings. Be sure to read the man page first. Unlike most Unix commands, it replaces its input file in place rather than writing the filtered output to stdout.